# cockpit configuration not being picked up

Tags: configuration, sap-commerce-cloud

I created my own cockpit from the ycockpit template, called TestCockpit. When I log into this cockpit, a List of Orders is displayed on the browser area.

I've configured the `listView` and the `editorArea`, both using XML files according to convention. The files are named **listViewContentBrowser_Order.xml** and **editorArea_Order.xml**, and are both placed under the folder for the ordermanagergroup user group.

When I run an update running system, the listView is affected by my configuration but the editorArea not.

This is what my editorArea config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<editor>
    <group qualifier="General" visible="true" initially-opened="true">
        <label key="testcockpit.config.label.properties"/>
        <property qualifier="Order.code"/>
        <property qualifier="Order.user"/>
        <property qualifier="Order.currency" visible="false"/>
        <property qualifier="Order.date"/>
        <property qualifier="Order.displayStatus"/>        
    </group>

    <group qualifier="admin" visible="true" initially-opened="false">
        <label key="cockpit.config.label.administration"/>
        <property qualifier="Item.pk" />
        <property qualifier="Item.creationTime" />
        <property qualifier="Item.modifiedtime" />
    </group>

    <custom-group
        class="de.hybris.platform.cockpit.services.config.impl.UnassignedEditorSectionConfiguration"
        qualifier="unassigned"
        initially-opened="false">
        <label key="cockpit.config.label.other"/>
    </custom-group>
</editor>
```

Any ideas why my configuration doesn't affect the cockpit? I do log in with a user from the ordermanagergroup, by the way.

Comment: I know the answer but I'm not putting it out there for all to see. If you are working on Hybris then you must be a partner and have forum access. I'll tell you there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clicking on "Menu" (top left in your cockpit), then selecting "User Settings" and "Reset Personalized Settings".